# Bukkit countdown doubles when 2 players online

Tags: java

I'v just created a countdown for a minigame im working on but when i was about to test the countdown i noticed that if i was the only one online the countdown worked perfect, but when another player joined the countdown doubled like this: 10,8,6,4 etc. I think it has something todo with "for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){" but i am not quite sure. Anyone that can help?

Here is my countdown class:

```
Main plugin;

public StartCountdown(Main pl) {
    plugin = pl;
}

public static int timeUntilStart;

@Override
public void run() {
    for(Player p1 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
            if(timeUntilStart == 0) {

                if(!Game.canStart()) {

                    plugin.restartCountdown();
                    ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "Not enough players to start. Countdown will");
                    ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "restart.");
                    p1.playSound(p1.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERDRAGON_WINGS, 5, 1);
                    return;
                }
                Game.start();
            }

                if(timeUntilStart == 1) {
            }
             for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
                    p.setLevel(timeUntilStart);

            if(timeUntilStart < 11  || timeUntilStart == 60 || timeUntilStart == 30) {
                p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 0);
                if(timeUntilStart == 1) {
                    p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 1);
                }
                ChatUtilities.broadcast(String.valueOf(timeUntilStart)
                        + " §6Seconds until the game starts!");
                }

            timeUntilStart -= 1;
        }

             if(timeUntilStart == 0) {
                 ChatUtilities.broadcast("§6The round has started, good luck!");
             }






}
```

}
}

Comment: You have two nested for loops... That do the same thing. Not good

Comment: I started editing your code to make the indentation more consistent, but there's some parts that I couldn't make sense out of. Should this block be empty? `if(timeUntilStart == 1) { }`

Comment: Yes. Forgot to edit and remove some useless lines in the code, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to decrement time (`timeUntilStart -= 1;`) is inside a loop `for(Player p1 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers())...`.
This means that for each player online, you decrement timeUntilStart by one. However, you only want to do that once per run - take it outside of the for each player p1 loop.

With that being said, most of this logic only should be happening once per RUN, not per player per run (i.e. unless you know something I don't, `game.start` should probably only get called once)... but that's irrelevant so I'll leave it alone.